# How to make build timeout in jenkins pipeline groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I saw declarative timeout example, e.g.

```
options{
  timeout(100)
}
```

but it cannot work in my groovy file for jenkins pipeline. Also, I cannot find more documentation about this API on jenkins site.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the timeout inside the `stage`.

```
stage ("deploy") {
  steps {
    script {
      try {
        timeout(time: 180, unit: 'SECONDS') {
          sh("RUN COMMAND")
        }
      }
      catch (err) {
        echo "Timeout."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't use `try/catch`, a timeout would cause a failure of this build, then your build will be interrupted on this stage.