# Jenkins checkout is timing out after 10 minutes

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, timeout

I have a pipeline, and I do a checkout step with the git plugin.

And the checkout step fails, due to a timeout issue, after 10 minutes.

After my research, I found out that the git plugins default timeout value is 10 minutes (exactly my problem)

After further research, I found out that you can modify that time with a extension, like this:

```
 Map checkout_settings = [
        changelog: true,
        scm: [
            $class: 'GitSCM',
            userRemoteConfigs: [
                [
                    credentialsId: ((Map) settings.credentials)?.id?.toString()?.trim() 
                    url: sttings.scmUrl.toString().trim()
                ]
            ],
            branches: [branch],
            extensions: [
                [
                    $class: 'CheckoutOption',
                    timeout: 70
                ],
                [
                    $class: 'CloneOption',
                    timeout: 70,
                    shallow: true,
                    depth: 1,
                    noTags: true
                ],
                [
                    $class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory',
                    relativeTargetDir: settings.executeFrom?.toString()?.trim() ?: ''
                ],
                [
                    $class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                    disableSubmodules: ((Map) settings.submodules)?.checkout != 'all' ?: false,
                    parentCredentials: true,
                    recursiveSubmodules: ((Map) settings.submodules)?.recursive ?: false,
                    timeout: 70
                ],
                [
                    $class: 'ScmName',
                    name: settings.scmName?.toString()?.trim() ?: settings.scmUrl.toString().trim()
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

I set the clone and checkout option to have timeout of 70 minutes, and simply sent those settings to the checkout step.

```
checkout(checkout_settings)
```

I expected that to solve my issue, but my problem still remains, as you can see from the log bellow:

```
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential sshkey
Cloning the remote Git repository
Using no checkout clone with sparse checkout.
Cloning repository ssh://git@bitbucket.trt.io/lww/ekkjp-sp2013-responsive.git
 > git init F:\ws\EJP\EJP-Core\Core\EJP_Core\1631 # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@bitbucket.trt.io/lww/ekkjp-sp2013-responsive.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.30.0.windows.2'
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://git@bitbucket.trt.io/lww/ekkjp-sp2013-responsive.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress -- ssh://git@bitbucket.trt.io/lww/ekkjp-sp2013-responsive.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 130:
```

The chekcout starts, and goes for a while, the precentiges are beeing displayed, until this happends:

```
Receiving objects:  84% (258842/307384), 896.07 MiB | 11.99 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  84% (258842/307384), 909.63 MiB | 12.53 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  84% (259843/307384), 927.31 MiB | 12.55 MiB/s
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2639)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2079)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:601)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:830)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:154)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 10.234.12.21/10.234.12.21:49686
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1800)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor823.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1223)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1301)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

It still times out at 10 minutes.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

That means it is not at the Jenkins level the timeout has to be set.
Jenkins main controller needs to access through SSH to a remote Git repository hosting server (`bitbucket.trt.io` in your case). So check you SSH settings, as [described here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Increase-ssh-connection-timeout/qaq-p/1857532):

> Check the files `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file (system-wide ssh configuration) and `~/.ssh/config` (ssh configuration for your user) in your laptop, and see if there are any values set for `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` (either for `Host *` or for `Host bitbucket.trt.io`).
>
> If you don't see these options in any of the two files, what you can do to keep the connection open for longer would be to add the following in either of the files:
>
> ```
> Host bitbucket.trt.io
>  ServerAliveInterval 300
>  ServerAliveCountMax 2
> ```
>
> The above values are just an example and you can adjust them depending on how long your hook needs to finish.
> What these settings will do is make your SSH client send a null packet to Bitbucket every 300 seconds (5 minutes) and give up if it doesn't receive a response after 2 tries. This will give you 10 minutes before the connection times out, if the hook takes longer to complete you can set a higher value to either or both of the options.

For you, `~/.ssh/config` means `/home/<the-account-used-by-Jenkins>/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I checked my server, on C:/Users/my-jenkins-user/.ssh and the config file was not present, there are only id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files, alongside with the known_hosts file... Am I missing somehting?

I tried this as well with a normal usernamePassword credentials (no SSH, but HTTP protocol) and it was the same, any suggestion on that?

Comment: @Elydasian I don't know why the same timeout would apply when using HTTPS. A TLS timeout?

Comment: I don't know either. Thank you for your time anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the checkout() call in a timeout block in order to override the default Jenkins timeout

```
timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES') {
    def checkout_values = checkout(checkout_settings)
}
```

Similar to this example:
[How to make build timeout in jenkins pipeline groovy script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61884153/how-to-make-build-timeout-in-jenkins-pipeline-groovy-script#61884921)